# Hide mobile navigation with jquery when anchor link is clicked

Tags: jquery, mobile

I've created a one-page scrolling site and the navigation naturally consists of anchor links. I've been able to get the mobile navigation to disappear when an anchor link is clicked (as shown in the jQuery code below), but when I click the mobile navigation icon, I have to click it twice for the navigation to reappear.

Is there any way to reset the navigation to its default coding with jquery when an anchor link is clicked? Here is what I have so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.Menu-link').on('click', function() {
        $(".Menu-list").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.HiddenCheckbox {
    display: none;
}
.MenuContainer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #333;
    height:30px;
}
.MenuHeader {
    color: #999999;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, opacity 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.6s, opacity 0.5s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.MenuIcon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.MenuIcon::before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: #999999 0 12px 0;
    box-shadow: #999999 0 12px 0;
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 30px;
}
.MenuIcon::after {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    width: 30px;
}
.MenuIcon::before, .MenuIcon::after {
    background: #999999;
    display: block;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s linear, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.2s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear, transform 0.4s 0.2s;
}
.Menu {
    background: #333;
    left: -125%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
    transition: left 0.4s;
}
.HiddenCheckbox:checked ~ .MenuHeader {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
.HiddenCheckbox:checked ~ .MenuIcon::before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: transparent 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: transparent 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(6px, -3px, 0);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(6px, -3px, 0);
}
.HiddenCheckbox:checked ~ .MenuIcon::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate3d(6px, 3px, 0);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate3d(6px, 3px, 0);
}
.HiddenCheckbox:checked ~ .Menu {
    left: 0;
}
.Menu-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 70px 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.Menu-item {
    margin: 0;
}
.Menu-link {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 22px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Menu-link::before {
    background: #444;
    bottom: 0;
    content:'';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.4s;
    transition: right 0.4s;
    z-index: -1;
}
.Menu-link::after {
    display:none;
    content: attr(href);
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.Menu-link:hover::before {
    right: 0;
}
.Menu-link:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="MenuContainer">
    <input id="menu" type="checkbox" name="menu" class="HiddenCheckbox" />
    <label for="menu" class="MenuIcon"></label>
    <h2 class="MenuHeader">Menu</h2>

    <nav class="Menu">
        <ul class="Menu-list">
            <li class="Menu-item">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="Menu-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu-item">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="Menu-link">Sample Chapter</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu-item">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="Menu-link">Author</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu-item">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="Menu-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="Menu-item">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="Menu-link">Links & Resources</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger click of your close button when anchor link is clicked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.Menu-link').on('click', function() {
        $(".MenuIcon").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Your previous code:

```
$(".Menu-list").hide();
```

This code was just hiding  element but not unchecking hidden checkbox and your CSS is based on checked property of hidden checkbox.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a simple solution, but I'm new to jQuery. I really appreciate the explanation too - such a huge help!

Comment: @greatwanderer, I am glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/muzati/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.Menu-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // if needed.

        // $(".Menu-list").hide();             // insetad of hard-hiding...
        $(".HiddenCheckbox").trigger("click"); // symulate the menu icon click
    });
});
```